# localizing subcategories of a nice triangulated category

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, triangulated-categories

Suppose that $D(A)$ is the derived category of of a ring A. Let $b\in D(A)$ be a compact object and $B$ the localizing subcategory  generated by b (having arbitrary coproduct).

Does the inclusion functor $ D(A)\leftarrow B: i$ have a left adjoint ?
Let $W: D(A)\rightarrow B$ the right adjoint to the inclusion functor. Do we have that $W\circ i=id$ ? Does W preserve compact objects?

Remark: the existence of a right adjoint to the inclusion functor is well known.

Comment: Is there any reason to suspect this is true? Take $A = D(R)$ for, say, a Noetherian regular local ring $(R,\mathfrak{m},k)$, and take $b = k$. The localizing subcategory generated by $k$ is then the derived category $\mathfrak{m}$-torsion $R$-modules. The inclusion will not, in general, preserve limits.

Comment: @DrewHeard does that localizing subcategory even have products?

Comment: @FernandoMuro For $Y,\{X_i\} \in \text{Loc}(b)$ we have $[Y,W \prod_i {X_i}] = [i(Y),\prod {X_i}] = \prod_i [i(Y),X_i] = \prod_i [Y,W(X_i)]$. So I think the product is just the product in $D(A)$ followed by $W$.

Comment: @DrewHeard you're right, so it's just that $i$ doesn't preserve products.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, there is no reason for the functor to have a left adjoint in general, as the inclusion will not preserve limits.

For the other two questions, the inclusion functor is fully-faithful, which occurs if and only if the unit map $\text{id} \to W \circ i$ is an equivalence. Finally, $A \in D(A)$ is compact, but $W(A) \in \text{Loc}(b)$ will typically not be.

Remark: In the literature, $W$ would be called a colocalization functor. A lot of facts and theorems can be found in the literature - for example, Section 3 of [Hovey, Palmieri, Strickland](https://hopf.math.purdue.edu/Hovey-Palmieri-Strickland/axiomatic.pdf).